# Capitalise the first character of text input

Tags: javascript, for-loop, input, char, uppercase

I cannot see where I am going wrong with this. My code is...

```
function firstC()
    {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("uValue");

        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        }
    }
```

It is called by...

```
<td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="(required)" id="firstName" class="uValue" onclick="empty(this.id)" onblur="firstC()" /></td>
```

The  `empty()` function works correctly by removing the value of the input box if its value is "(required)", but I cannot get the `firstC()` function to capitalise the first character of any input.

EDIT: I am using `getElementsByClassName` as there are multiple input boxes which I am trying to allow to use the same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to assign the value back

```
function firstC()
    {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("uValue");

        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].value = x[i].value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x[i].value.substr(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, you missed index too :-) (Fixed in answer)

Comment: Ah damn! I need to come on here more often, long before I spend hours racking my brain. This works - thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 2):

You should instead pass the `this` into your inline JS eventers:

```
onclick="empty(this)" onblur="firstC(this)"
```

Example

```js
function empty(el) {  // el now refers to the this referrer
  el.value="";
}

function firstC(el) {
  var val = el.value;
  el.value = val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.substr(1);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onclick="empty(this)" onblur="firstC(this)"  value="(required)" id="firstName" class="uValue" name="firstname">
```

P.S: don't forget that instead of using `empty()` and `value="(required)"` you can simply use the `placeholder` attribute

```
placeholder="(required)"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's nice to see alternative methods to do things, and I tested this one as well so I know it works :). Thank you for the heads up about the placeholder, too!